# Getting access to the form params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with hidden field:

```html
<%= f.hidden_field(:equipment_id, :value => " ") %>
```

The value for this field is submitted via js. So that my generated html looks like this:

```html
<input value="2" type="hidden" name="programm[equipment_id]" id="programm_equipment_id">
```

When i submit my form my parameters look like this:

```html
"programm"=>{
  .. some other params ..,
 "equipment_id"=>"2"
}
```

In my controller's create method I try to assign equipment_id parameter to @programm.equipment_id:

```html
@programm.equipment_id = params[:programm => :equipment_id ]
```

like that. Where equipment_id is an integer column in database.
The problem is that nothing gets assigned. If i try to cast .to_i "0" is being assigned and stored in database.
I also tried to do:

```html
@programm.equipment_id = params[:equipment_id ]
```

But the problem is the same.

Comment: Did you create your controller/model/... by using the rails scaffolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
@programm.equipment_id = params[:programm][:equipment_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

The params are nested. You can access it like this:

```
@programm.equipment_id = params[:programm][:equipment_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

**for the view like this:-**

```
<%= form_for(@programm) do |f|%>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:equipment_id, :value => " ") %>
<%end%>
```

Upon form submission the value entered by the user will be stored in `params[:programm][:equipment_id]` and can be used to access the value.